# Gson JSON Output contains spaces in field names after conversion

Tags: json, spring-mvc, gson

I have an unusual situation. The encoded output contains json with space between every character .

```
{ " f o r m " : { " s a m p l e F i e l d " : " s a m p l e v a l u e " } }
```

We have a spring mvc application and 
perform a POST request to one of our controllers. The fields within the POST request are populated in POJO from request parameters. From our logs we can see that there are no spaces between the letters.. We are passing our POJO directly to a shared instance of Gson within our service class **( many requests & quartz background threads use this instance)**. The  Gson converter variable is instantiated as follows

```
Gson gsonMaker = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy").create();
```

This is quite random (1 case in 100) Request pointers to look out.
We store the JSON output in Oracle 11g database.
From my reading on other posts & googling, Gson seems to be thread safe.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

After much analysis, the issue was found to be with ojdbc6 driver jar. It turns out that the driver has a problem with CLOB field and it happens only with 8000 characters.
The sequence to reproduce this problem is as below.

1. Create a Database table  in Oracle with CLOB column
2. Write exactly 8000 characters into a string.
3. Insert the string data into CLOB field.
4. Read the inserted data using resultset.getString("CLOB_FIELD")
5. The data read in step 4 will now have characters interleaved with NUL (\u0000) characters.

Our DAL using hibernate was fetching the CLOB data and saving it again into DB. This re-write of 8000 characters back to the database triggered a confusion that it may be happening due to Gson.

There are a couple of questions to which I am trying to figure out an answer.

1. If the Hibernate Entity is annotated with @Lob(which saves the CLOB data), why still hibernate chooses to read it as a string causing the read data corrupt?. Shouldn't hibernate handle this?
2. This issue is rare and has been discussed in this thread [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3647914?start=0&tstart=0), but I did not find any mention for a fix in latest drivers (I am yet to test this for latest drivers).

Hope people find this thread useful.